# Conditional replacement while match on a variable

Tags: r, if-statement, replace, dplyr, na

I want to replace the `NA` values for observations within a particular sub-group, but the sequence of the observations in that group is not ordered properly. So I am wondering if there exists some `dplyr` or `plyr` command that would allow me to replace missing values in a column belonging to one dataframe using the values from the same column from another dataframe while matching on the values of that "key" column.

Here's what I got. Hope someone could shed light on this. Thanks.

```css
## data frame that contains missing values in "diff" column

df <- data.frame(type = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), 
diff = c(0.1, 0.3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.2, 0.7, NA, 0.5, NA), 
name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "A", "B", "C", "F", "A", "B", "C"))

## replace with values from this smaller data frame

df2 <- data.frame(diff_rep = c(0.3, 0.2, 0.4), name = c("A", "B", "C"))

## replace using ifelse
df$diff <- ifelse(is.na(df$diff) & (df$type == 2), df2$diff_rep , df$diff)

df

   type diff name
1     1  0.1    A
2     1  0.3    B
3     1   NA    C
4     2  0.3    D
5     2  0.2    E
6     2  0.4    A
7     2  0.3    B
8     2  0.2    C
9     2  0.7    F
10    3   NA    A
11    3  0.5    B
12    3   NA    C

## desired output

   type diff name
1     1  0.1    A
2     1  0.3    B
3     1   NA    C
4     2   NA    D
5     2   NA    E
6     2  0.3    A
7     2  0.2    B
8     2  0.4    C
9     2  0.7    F
10    3   NA    A
11    3  0.5    B
12    3   NA    C
```

Comment: Can you explain how the values are replaced? Not clear to me. Also I see that row 9 `0.7` is replaced with `NA`.

Comment: Also what is `## replace using ifelse` part ? Is it part of your original `df` ?

Comment: What I am saying is that D E F of `type` 2 should result in no match. They should have looked like my desired output at below.

Comment: @Ronak, the `df` is the new dataframe after implementing `itelse()`.

Comment: So why `A` and `C` has `NA` for `type` 3 when `A` and `B` are present in `df2` ? Same for `C` in `type` 1 ?

Comment: The coding is based on type (the "group" label).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuminhg row 9 is a mistake, you can use a left join first and then use `ifelse()` and `coalesce()` to get your desired result. `coalesce()` returns the first non-missing value

```
left_join(df, df2, by = "name") %>% 
  mutate(diff_wanted = if_else(type == 2,
                               coalesce(diff, diff_rep),
                               diff),
         diff_wanted = ifelse(name %in% df2$name,
                              diff_wanted,
                              NA)) %>% 
  select(type, diff_wanted, name)
```

Comment: name D, E, F should result in no match, as `df2` does not contain values for name D, E, F.

Comment: I think I got it, just use `df$diff <- df2$diff[match(df$name, df2$name)]` should do the trick.

Comment: I added another ifelse clause

Comment: Hi @mnist, the F of `type` 2 result in NA, while it should have been 0.7.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I didn't notice I mis-coded obs 9 (the F of `type` 2). Please accept my apology.